# OK to use an http header to send ssl signature between 2 apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, http-headers

We have 2 rails applications which talk to each other via API's. We decided we wanted to secure the calls using OpenSSL with public and private keys. So before sending a request, we create a signature of a document using the private key. On the other app we verify the signature with the public key and the received document.

This works well for our PUTs and POSTs because we can simply add the document and the signature in the Body.

However we also want to do it for GETs, and I do not want to add a body to a get, apparently this is a no-no. Would it be appropriate to send the signature and the document as http headers in the GET request? The document is very small - just a few arguments in a JSON string.

The other option I have is to use POSTs or PUTs instead of GETs

Comment: This should work exactly the same. Whether you send it as a header (say `Authorization: `) or in the `POST` body, that should have no impact on security.

Comment: **Note**: This method is fundamentally insecure, because you are reusing a signature, so an attacker to perform a replay attack if they have access to the data you send over. [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ADigital_signature#Replay_attack)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, within the document I was thinking of having a timestamp, and also checking the time is close as well as verifying the signature.  What is the best practice for securing API calls between 2 apps, or at least a better way? (this may be another SO question)

Comment: So if you're using a timestamp, that's better, but not perfect from what I know. Using a unique [cryptographically strong random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) number per request would be a better bet, or you could use [HTTPS and verify the client](http://serverfault.com/questions/330872/how-can-i-verify-a-clients-identity-using-an-ssl-handshake-to-allow-access-to-c)

Comment: interesting thanks, so I would have to store this number somewhere and reject any future requests that have the same random number. or I could store the last x minutes worth of numbers and use the timestamp in the document to ensure the request is both unique and recent, meaning I would not have to store an unlimited number of random numbers.

Comment: That's a good point. In general, this is why it's best not to roll your own authentication protocols! With the concerns you bring up, what we're basically converging on is a private key-signed [Diffie Hellman Key Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange)

Comment: problem now when I send the signature as part of the body in a POST, encoding arrives as UTF-8, but when sent as a header in a GET, encoding arrives as ASCII-8BIT. So signature verification fails. trying to force encoding is too hard so I'm giving up on the header in GET request approach. As Jeremy says, I should probably look into some standard authentication protocol, but its fun trying to work it out, and from what I see [here in a railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api?view=asciicast), looks like some standard API securing approaches are open to replay-attacks too.

Comment: You could always [Base64-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) your token. This is what [JSON Web Tokens](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token#what-are-json-web-tokens?) do to overcome this hurdle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79721/discussion-between-ryan2johnson9-and-jeremy-blalock).